# Java app: Windows Service interacting with the system tray icon

Tags: java, system-tray, java-service-wrapper

I am creating a Windows Service with Java Wrapper Service and I want to interact with the user through a system tray icon.

According to the library the solution would be to create an "interactive service" but this is not recommanded by Microsoft Windows.

See https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html

and https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

My tray icon would be the "GUI part" and the service wrapper would be the "engine part". What is the best way to communicate between these two parts?

Comment: were you eventually able to resolve this problem?

Comment: @hdf You have to create a "back" app (installed as a windows service) and a "front" app. When you start the GUI (front), it starts the service. Front and back exchanges via web services or JMX for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create ONE application running as service and also having a system tray icon. No need to separate the two.

Just create a regular .jar file and run it with a wrapper service. Then just add a TrayIcon to the .jar and it will pop up in the system tray.

Use `SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(yourTrayIcon);` to add it the system tray. You can hook up any GUI you like and also easily add a menu to it.

Comment: This is what I have done; but Windows disabled desktop interaction from services as mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx "Typically, services are console applications that are designed to run unattended without a graphical user interface (GUI)"

Comment: But I also read: However, an interactive service can display a user interface and receive user input.

Comment: Yes of course, but I already tried without succeed. I also need to change a registry key... but I cannot do that on every pc. And the page also "the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code.".

Comment: The article says anothe solution: "Create a separate hidden GUI application and use the CreateProcessAsUser function to run the application within the context of the interactive user" but I'm writting in Java, I do not understand what they mean

Comment: OK, I understand, but I don't get it fully. I have a solution with an interactive service in production, running without any problems (on Windows 8). Sorry, I could not help...

Answer (score 0):

your problem can be resolve with JavaExe